# flink on docker disk full

Tags: docker, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I created a very small cluster in docker (1 job manager 3 task manager). I have 2 jobs (1 streaming and 1 batch which is restarted when it's finished).

I have 58G free space (approx. 30G used). When I start the aggregator, the job manager started to eat the disk. After some hour my disk is full. But when I check the FS (`du -su /*/`), it only contains about 30G of files.

I do not understand why it's happened, and where is the data.
I try to check inside the jobmanager container but no success.

Any idea?

Comment: Check log files of Apache Flink.

Comment: Nothing interesting. I got no space left on device.... and that's all.. the log size is ~20M... and this container eat 40G (the jobmanager).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it appears it was the .out file in the /usr/local/flink-{1-0.3}/log folder which was over 6GB. I had to delete the file and redeploy the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Docker Meta for Mac? I had a "full disk space" issue and I couldn't build my projects anymore. The steps that worked for me:

1) df -h --> check that the host has enough available space

**If that's the case, do the following:**

1) docker exec -it your-container bash --> connect to your container

2) df -h /var/www --> check disk space

**If there's no more available space, exit the container and do the following:**

1) docker rm $(docker ps -aq) --> stop and delete all containers

2) docker rmi --> delete all images

3) ls -lh ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2 --> check this file size and delete it

4) quit Docker and reopen it

5) quit the terminal and reopen it

6) Build again

Comment: Thanks but please read the question again.
The main problem is not how can I control my docker container. 
The problem is: my container eat the disk (while it's run flink job manager)  but no visible file in the filesystem (host and guest). So when I started the job manager and I push jobs into it. The disk will be full, but(!) if I delete the job manager I got back all space...
I try to find the "big file" in the container and in the host too.

ps: It's running on ubuntu